# Inserir itens clonados no formulário com PHP e Mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql-insert, clone

Amigos, estou com problemas para gravar no MySQL campos clonados no formulário.
Vou tentar explicar com detalhes pra ver se os amigos conseguem me ajudar.

```html
<div class="mb-md">
    <a href="#" id="but_add">
        <i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i>
        <span class="text-semibold text-primary"> Adicionar Categoria</span>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="categoria row" id="categoria">
<section class="panel panel-border">
<header class="panel-heading">
    <div class="pull-right">
        <a href="#" class="text-primary text-semibold remove-categoria">Excluir</a>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="ds_categoriacomp[]" class="form-control-small-height" placeholder="Nome" data-plugin-maxlength maxlength="100" required>
    <div class="row col-padding-top-x15">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Qtd.</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">min</span>
                        <input type="number" id="qtd_min" name="qtd_min[]" value="0" min="0" max="99" maxlength="2" step="1" required="required" class="form-control-small-height qtd_min"/>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">máx</span>
                        <input type="number" id="qtd_max" name="qtd_max[]" min="1" max="99" maxlength="2" step="1" required="required" class="form-control-small-height"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 pull-right custom-padding-top-x7">
            <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
                <input type="checkbox" name="cd_obrigatorio[]"/>
                <label>Obrigatório</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:-15px;">
    <table class="table mb-none tb-complementos" id="tb-complementos">
        <tr>
            <td class="actions col-sm-2">
            <input id="ds_complemento" name="ds_complemento[]" placeholder="Nome" class="form-control-small-height" data-plugin-maxlength maxlength="100" required>
            </td>
            <td class="actions col-lg-4">
            <input id="ds_descComp" name="ds_desccomp[]" placeholder="Descrição" class="form-control-small-height" data-plugin-maxlength maxlength="2000" required>
            </td>
            <td class="actions text-center col-lg-1">
            <input id="vl_valorcomp" name="vl_valorcomp[]" class="form-control-small-height" placeholder="Preço" onkeyup="formatarMoeda(this);" onChange="carregaPrValor(this.value);" required>
            </td>
            <td class="actions text-center col-lg-1">
                <a href="#" class="remove-complemento">
                    <span class="text-semibold">Excluir</span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <a href="#" id="but_add_c" class="but_add_c" style="padding-left:10px;">
        <i class="fa fa-plus text-dark"></i>
        <span class="text-semibold text-dark"> Adicionar complemento</span>
    </a>
</div>
</section>
</div>
```

O HTML acima, gera formulário na imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar em **Adicionar complemento**, a função js faz um clone dos campos complementos conforme a imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar em **Adicionar categoria** a funcão js gera um clone do formulário completo, onde dentro deste formulário "clone" eu posso adicionar mais complementos e assim por diante. Figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aí é onde ocorre o problema. Como posso salvar no banco de dados visto que são duas tabelas, **tabela1** grava o nome da categoria e **tabela2** grava os complementos.

Abaixo a forma como estou tentando fazer no PHP, mas sem sucesso:

```html
for($i = 0; $i < count($nomecategoria); $i++){
 mysql_query("insert into tabela1 (nomecategoria, valor1, valor2...)values('".$nomecategoria[$i]."', '".$valor1[$i]."', '".$valor2[$i]."')");
 //busca id da categoria gerado no insert
 $idcategoria = mysql_insert_id();
}
for($c = 0; $c < count($nomecomplemento); $c++){
 mysql_query("insert into tabela2 (idcategoria, nomecomplemento, descricao)values('".$idcategoria."', '".$nomecomplemento[$c]."', '".$descricao[$c]."')");
}
```

O código acima salva as categorias na **tabela1** corretamente, mas ao salvar os complementos na **tabela2** o **idcategoria** fica sempre igual.

JavaScript que faz o clone dos objetos:

```js
//add categoria complemento/////////////////////////////////
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#but_addcategoria').click(function(){
   var newel = $('.categoria:last')
   .clone(true)
   .find("input").val("").end()
   $(newel).insertAfter(".categoria:last"); 
  });
});
//add item complemento 
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#but_addcomplemento').click(function(){
   var newel = $('.tb-complementos:last')
   .clone(true)
   .find("input").val("").end();
   $(newel).insertBefore(this);
  });
});
```

Existe uma forma ideal para fazer esses inserts de maneira que cada complemento fique com seu **idcategoria** correto?

Desde já agradeço os amigos que tentarem ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A única forma que vejo é você criando índices e subíndices nas arrays dos complementos. Por exemplo, no primeiro formulário de categoria, os names dos complementos ficariam numa sequência:

```
Complemento 1:
name="ds_complemento[0][0]"
name="ds_desccomp[0][0]"
name="vl_valorcomp[0][0]"

Complemento 2:
name="ds_complemento[0][1]"
name="ds_desccomp[0][1]"
name="vl_valorcomp[0][1]"
```

E por aí vai. No segundo formulário:

```
Complemento 1:
name="ds_complemento[1][0]"
name="ds_desccomp[1][0]"
name="vl_valorcomp[1][0]"

Complemento 2:
name="ds_complemento[1][1]"
name="ds_desccomp[1][1]"
name="vl_valorcomp[1][1]"
```

Veja que o primeiro índice (o primeiro colchetes) segue uma sequência do formulário inteiro, onde `[0]` é o primeiro, `[1]` o segundo etc. O segundo colchetes os índices dos complementos vinculados à categoria.

Neste caso, você teria que fazer isso no JavaScript que clona os elementos, para que ele ordene corretamente os campos com os índices nos colchetes.

Com isso, o PHP irá receber os complementos numa subarray, tal como:

```
[ds_categoriacomp] => Array
   (
      [0] => cat 1
      [1] => cat 2
   )
[ds_complemento] => Array
   (
      [0] => Array
         (
            [0] => cat1 comp1
            [1] => cat1 comp2
         )

      [1] => Array
         (
            [0] => cat2 comp1
         )
   )
```

Note que agora cada índice da subarray `[ds_complemento]` está relacionada a uma categoria a uma categoria: índice `[0]` = 1ª categoria, índice `[1]` = 2ª categoria etc.

Com isso, seu `for` ficaria desta forma, um dentro do outro, alterando o `$nomecomplemento` para o índice do primeiro `for`, ou seja, `$nomecomplemento[$i]`:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($nomecategoria); $i++){
    mysql_query("insert into tabela1 (nomecategoria, valor1, valor2...)values('".$nomecategoria[$i]."', '".$valor1[$i]."', '".$valor2[$i]."')");
    //busca id da categoria gerado no insert
    $idcategoria = mysql_insert_id();
   for($c = 0; $c < count($nomecomplemento[$i]); $c++){
      mysql_query("insert into tabela2 (idcategoria, nomecomplemento, descricao)values('".$idcategoria."', '".$nomecomplemento[$c]."', '".$descricao[$c]."')");
   }
}
```

### Clonando os elementos

Crie uma função que será chamada toda vez que você clonar ou excluir elementos. Essa função irá alterar os atributos `name` dos complementos criando subíndices ordenados e vinculados ao índices das categorias:

```
function subIndices(){
   var cats = $(".categoria");
   cats.each(function(idx){
      var tabs = $(this).find(".tb-complementos");
      var cidx = idx;
      tabs.each(function(idx){
         $(this).find("[name^='ds_complemento']").attr("name", "ds_complemento["+cidx+"]["+idx+"]");
         $(this).find("[name^='ds_desccomp']").attr("name", "ds_desccomp["+cidx+"]["+idx+"]");
         $(this).find("[name^='vl_valorcomp']").attr("name", "vl_valorcomp["+cidx+"]["+idx+"]");
      });
   });
}
```

Você irá chamar essa função no final de todos os eventos que clonam ou excluem elementos, tal como:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#but_addcomplemento').click(function(){
      var newel = $('.tb-complementos:last')
      .clone(true)
      .find("input").val("").end();
      $(newel).insertBefore(this);
      subIndices(); // CHAMA A FUNÇÃO
     });
});
```

Como eu disse, coloque `subIndices();` no final de todos os eventos.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Sam. Meu js que clona o objeto é bem simples, adicionei o código no final da pergunta. Você teria alguma dica de como criar os índices e subíndices nas arrays dos complementos? 

Abraço!

Comment: Vou tentar fazer aqui e te aviso.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado Sam, vou testar e em seguida informo aqui o resultado.

Comment: Sam, agora ficou certo o idcategoria de cada complemento, porem os valores ds_complemento, ds_desccomp e vl_valorcomp, salvam na base uma string Array. No for do PHP fiz da forma que falou. Estranho pq os outros campos salvam corretamente.

Comment: Bom, já é alguma coisa. Vamos atrás agora do problema com a array.

Comment: Sim, já é bastante coisa. A forma que eu estava fazendo estava muito errada.

Comment: Acho que o `$nomecomplemento[$c]` e o `$descricao[$c]` deveriam ter o subíndice: `$nomecomplemento[$i][$c]` e `$descricao[$i][$c]`

Comment: Pronto, funcionou perfeitamente, era exatamente isso, faltava o subíndice nas variáveis.
Muito obrigado Sam, resolveu meu problema que estava a dias me batendo.